# Using local AD with IdentityServer4 in a Xamarin client application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, identityserver4

I am building a Xamarin app which will authenticate with Identity Server.  I have this working with ASP.NET Identity Core.  However, I'd like to be able to use AD as well.  The documentation states this is possible but gives no examples.  My biggest issue is that I'm using IdentityModel to manage my login calls, and I don't see any calls that seem to relate to AD.

I've discovered IExtensionGrantValidator, but I don't see any way, in that code, to work out the AD user logged in, in the client application.  I could obviously make the user my payload, but at that stage it doesn't seem secure enough to me.  I could make it work that way easily, but I'm hoping for a way that IdentityServer validates against the AD user, hopefully including that they are associated with a specific role.

I am hoping someone can point me to sample code for using AD (not Azure AD) with Identity Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html) is the documentation about the Windows Authentication. Also in the `AcountOptions.cs` set `public static bool WindowsAuthenticationEnabled = true;`, and have in mind:

> to enable windows authentication, the host (IIS or IIS Express) also must have windows auth enabled.

Then in the `AccountController.cs` you have a method "ExternalLogin" and there you have a check for Windows Authentication, where you can follow what happens, but the important work is the above.

Comment: Thanks - the docs are not very helpful, and no sample exists where it works.  The account controller is not called at all (mine is commented out) because I am connecting using the IdentityModel library in a client application.  So, my main problem is working out how to pass the Windows identity through on calls I make to the server, not in a browser, or how to pass log in using AD directly, via the IdentityModel libraries.

Comment: To be specific, windows auth is triggered by calling ChallengeAsync, but I don't see any way to do that, outside of a web server.  I don't see any way to call it from a client application. My fundamental issue is passing my AD user to the server, from a C# client application, preferably using the IdentityModel classes.  I found RequestClientCredentialsAsync, but that actually seems to just validate against a client without requiring any further user details.